# Setting up python with [import package] instead of [from package import package]

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

When using my library after uploading to pypi I have to use `from package import package`, instead of just `import package`. How can I change this?

My setup.py file:

```
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup

# The directory containing this file
HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

# The text of the README file
README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()

# This call to setup() does all the work
setup(
    name="cool-library",
    version="0.5.3",
    description="Libary",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/user/repo",
    author="Author",
    author_email="user@site.com",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    ],  
    packages=["mylib"],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "cool-library=mylib.__main__:main",
        ]   
    },  
)
```

This is the directory layout:

```
cool-library
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── mylib
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── mylib.py
```

How can I rearrange it so I can import directly? I tried doing `package_dir = {'':'mylib'}` but that was not working for me.

Comment: What package is that? I can't reproduce the error with the code you provided.

Comment: That is an example of a pypi package

Comment: I got that - what is the real lib's name? The code in question doesn't cause any import errors after installation. If you want to keep your lib private, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try skilstak-colors and from skcolors import skcolors

Comment: There is no such package `skcolors` in the library. The only package bundled is named `colors` (as can be seen in the setup script: `packages=["colors"]`), so `from colors import colors` will work.

Comment: How can I use the expression import colors instead?